# what is deference between locationManager requestLocationUpdates and stopUpdatingLocation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

What is the main difference between `startUpdatingLocation`,`stopUpdatingLocation` Methods of CLLocationManager and `locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates` and `locationManagerDidResumeLocationUpdates`  methods.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Read this document

The CLLocationManager class defines the interface for configuring the delivery of location- and heading-related events to your application. You use an instance of this class to establish the parameters that determine when location and heading events should be delivered and to start and stop the actual delivery of those events. You can also use a location manager object to retrieve the most recent location and heading data.

A location manager object provides support for the following location-related activities:

Tracking large or small changes in the user’s current location with a configurable degree of accuracy.
Reporting heading changes from the onboard compass. (iOS only)
Monitoring distinct regions of interest and generating location events when the user enters or leaves those regions.
Deferring the delivery of location updates while the app is in the background. (iOS 6 and later only)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

Comment: but this is not the answer of my question :(

Comment: have you read your ref link??
in that there is nothing about `locationManagerDidResumeLocationUpdates`..

Comment: still this is not the answer of my question :(